Hosting Next.js on a Droplet with Existing WordPress Installation
I have a Droplet with WordPress set up and running smoothly. Now, I’d like to host a Next.js application on the same Droplet. I’ve tried various approaches but seem to be stuck. Could you provide a guide or recommend an article to help me with this setup?
Thank you!
